# Turn many features in a data frame with spark ML

Tags: scala, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I was following this tutorial https://mapr.com/blog/churn-prediction-sparkml/
and I realized that the csv structure had to be written by hand like this :

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("state", StringType, true),
    StructField("len", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("acode", StringType, true),
    StructField("intlplan", StringType, true),
    StructField("vplan", StringType, true),
    StructField("numvmail", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tdmins", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tdcalls", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tdcharge", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("temins", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tecalls", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("techarge", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tnmins", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tncalls", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("tncharge", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("timins", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("ticalls", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("ticharge", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("numcs", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("churn", StringType, true)
```

However I have a dataset with 335 features so I don't want to write them all... Is there a simple way to retrieve them and define the schema accordingly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here : https://dzone.com/articles/using-apache-spark-dataframes-for-processing-of-ta 
It was easier than I thought